# Cost-effective way to have good lighting for color-blind users

Tags: lighting

I live in a tropical area and the sunlight is generally 'hot' as opposed to what you'd see in the UK.

I'm also color-blind to some extent and I have a lot of trouble trying to get my indoor lighting in order.

1. Common CFL bulbs are killing - my eyes hurt a lot.
2. Tube lights have a simliarly irritating effect on my eyes.
3. I use 'warm white' CFLs mounted on the ceiling but the shades seem to create shadows.
4. I have to spend an average of 12 hours in this setting for work.
5. The tungstan bulbs are obviously expensive to use (running cost).
6. The best so far seem to be are the halogen lamps but they're costly and emit too much heat.

What solution is there to make cost-effective lighting that would be easy on my eyes and give out the effect of early-morning sunlight?

By the way, my walls and ceilings are white.

Comment: What is your voltage requirement and lighting base conventions?

Comment: We use 250V power. I'm only focusing on my work area. So that's about 20ft length x 15 width x 10ft height. BTW, that was a very good question.

Comment: Have you looked at LED bulbs? They are more expensive than incandescent or CFL, but prices are dropping (in the US, basic bulbs are as low as $10). They come in a range of color temperatures, including warm tones, and are dimmable (but may require specialized dimmers).

Comment: There are two problems with LEDs. First, like you've correctly stated, they're expensive. A decent holder with several little bulbs on it as about USD 30. From what I've seen in some malls, I think I'll need at least 10 of them in my space. I think the biggest threat is having to see the light coming straight from a bulb. The mere sight of a lit up bulb at night makes me feel tired. And to add to it, the reflection off my spectacles makes it even worse.

Comment: While these units are somewhat expensive, they have diffusers to soften the bulb glare: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-6-in-Recessed-White-LED-Retrofit-Trim-HCCER673WH/203010504#.Uhoo6pKKK8A

Comment: Experiment with a few LED lamps as task lighting to be sure the technology works for you before investing much money. Issues such as shades and diffusers are solvable if the technology works. With good task lighting, you may be able to use inexpensive CFLs for general lighting. The only practical technology not mentioned yet is HID, which are primarily for large industrial applications and often have poor color rendition, so LED may be your only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another solution that does not involve powered lighting could be to use 'Light Pipes' or 'Light Tubes' with 'Full' or 'Half' CTO (Colour Temperature Orange) filters clipped onto them inside the building.

Colour temperature orange filters are used in the TV and Film industries to transform the light source into a warmer more incandescent type of light in terms of its colour.  These gels can also withstand high temperatures.

Google 'CTO Gels'.  Wikipedia also has a clear article on 'Light Tubes'.

To dim the light you could then place 'Neutral Density' lighting gels over the CTO sheets.  Alternatively louvered shutters over the ends of the light pipes would allow you to fine tune the amount of light getting through.

The light pipe idea would mean free lighting after the install has been paid for and is a low tech but long term solution.

Comment: To me this is an invention of the 21st century - I never knew this until a today! Hmmm... Now I need to find a place to do this in Sri Lanka

Comment: Hi, the glass tube version looks expensive and difficult to find, however, the metal tube version looks as though a local Metal Fabricator could build one using an air con tube with a polished steel interior (sheet of polished steel curled up inside the main tube).  A roofing specialist could no doubt install it with a plastic or glass dome and rubber seal to keep the rain out. Inside the room something neat and tidy could be improvised :  Check out the first pic : http://www.greendiary.com/6-solar-light-pipes-designed-conserve-energy.html  Keep me posted :)